# Server Error in '/MvcApplication1' Application. The resource cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using window 10. VS 2013.

I created local IIS :

http://localhost/MvcApplication1.

When I tried to access, the problem occured:

`"Error in '/MvcApplication1' Application. The resource cannot be found."`

I tried another link : http://localhost/MvcApplication1/home/index, but it didn't fix the problem.

I have searched for 2 days, no solution can solve it. 
What should I do?

Comment: what's your default page in IIS?

Comment: my default website in IIS is MvcApplication1

Comment: What you see if you type `http://localhost` and `http://localhost:8080` in your browser and did you try creating an application directly in IIS with some test html page and browse it?

Comment: Go to your website in IIS. In right pane under IIS, you will see default document. Double click on it and see what's the default document there..

Comment: before update my VS, I could use IIS Express which like <http://localhost:port>, but now it has same problem

Comment: Try `aspnet_regiis -i` from Visual Studio command prompt and check if that fix.

Comment: Amitdayama, it is index.html.
 SivaGopal, I canot run aspnet_regiis.exe and I have tried to fix it for 2 days